# Relax Weight Paint?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I was wondering if there was any function in blender that average's weight paint's of vertices like it does in Maya here:
https://youtu.be/WQMjCm-KAis?t=216

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Maya rigging doesn't work exactly the same as Blender.  However, yes, there's something you can do here that's very similar, which is to use the "smooth" operation.  I generally call this operation from the searchbar, but you can also use it from the "weights" menu while in weight paint.  We'll look at the parameters available:

[image]

By default, smooth works on the actively selected vertex group only, but can be set to work on all groups.  For each vertex, it generates a new weight for the affected vertex groups from the weights of adjacent vertices, and then interpolates from existing weights on the basis of Factor.  If expand/contract is set to -1, it will only ever reduce weights; if expand/contract is set to 1, it will only ever increase weights.  It performs this operation a number of times equal to Iterations.

To use this to emulate the Relax operation, you can set the subset to All Groups and increase the expand/contract to 1.0 (or any positive value.)  This will increase the weights of all bones, but your armature will re-normalize these values, and you'll end up diffusing the influence of your individual bones.  Increase the iterations to increase how far the smoothing works.

There are a few things to be wary of.  First, if you have non-deforming vertex groups (like vertex groups used by a non-armature modifier) those will be smoothed by "all groups" as well, which you probably won't want.  Second, the smoothing only works on the basis of neighboring vertices, and doesn't take distance along mesh into account, so the amount of perceptual relaxation depends on the vertex density, which may vary in different parts of the mesh.

Comment: Thank you very much for this incredible answer - I think that's what I'm looking for, I just have a quick question as to the difference between active group, and selected bone pose bones? It seems like when you select a new bone, that becomes the active group automatically - Is active group = to the selected vertices? Or is it the vertex group affected by the current weight paint? 

Again, much appreciated the answer!!

Comment: @GoodNight On active group, smooth affects only the weights of the active group.  When you select a bone in pose mode, that sets the active vertex group to be the vertex group with the same name as the bone you just selected.  There isn't really such a thing as multi-group selection, although some weight paint operations (multi-paint) may emulate it.  In general, to get the effect you want, you need to affect all deforming groups, and since there isn't any subset like that for the operation, you need to affect all groups.  Selected vertices is different; unselected vertices will not change.

Comment: I see, thank you, I believe my question has been answered now-!!